# How can I use the Entity Framework Core capabilities to change my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am building an application on top of Entity Framework Core and I want to, sort of, apply a migration at runtime.

My intended approach is to have the current database model in memory and create a new model, then calculate the difference between the two models using `IMigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences().`

From there, instead of printing the differences into a `Migration` class, I want to create the `MigrationCommand`s directly and apply those commands to my database.

The above sounds fairly straightforward but I'm having a lot of issues with the Dependency Injection system.

This is the code I have right now:

```
static DbContextOptions GetOptions(IModel model)
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
    builder
        .UseSqlServer(connStr)
        .UseModel(model);
    return builder.Options;
}
class Test1ModelAEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StrProp { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sqlServerServices = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
    var conventions = new ConventionSet();
    sqlServerServices.GetRequiredService<IConventionSetBuilder>().AddConventions(conventions);

    var emptyModelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(conventions);
    var emptyModel = emptyModelBuilder.Model;

    var test1ModelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(conventions);
    test1ModelBuilder.Entity<Test1ModelAEntity>()
        .ToTable("ModelA");
    var test1Model = test1ModelBuilder.Model;

    using (TestContext ctx = new TestContext(GetOptions(emptyModel)))
    {
        var migrationServices = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddDbContextDesignTimeServices(ctx)
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        var operations = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>().GetDifferences(emptyModel, test1Model);
        var commands = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator>().Generate(operations, test1Model);
        var connection = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IRelationalConnection>();
        migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationCommandExecutor>().ExecuteNonQuery(commands, connection);
    }
}
```

This code throws a `NullReferenceException` with this stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.TableMapping.<>c.<GetRootType>b__10_0(IEntityType t)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetSortedProperties(TableMapping target)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.<Add>d__37.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.<DiffCollection>d__73`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
at Sandbox.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Sandbox\Program.cs:line 108
```

I have inspected the source code and it appears that there's an issue with the way EFCore is interpreting my model. I am using EFCore version 2.1 preview 2.

Really I'm mostly trying random configurations on my `IServiceCollection`s because I have no idea how to set this up. I am also trying to stay away from EFCore internal classes but if needed be I may use one or two for the time being.

Is there a way to take advantage of EFCore's built-in capabilities to generate some SQL given a pair of `IModel`s? If so, how do I set up DI to have all the required services?

Comment: why are you doing so complicated? you just run Add-Migration <YourMigrationName> and then run `Update-Database`

Comment: I want my DbContext to have a dynamic model. The model may change at runtime (new tables, columns, ...). For that, I need my application to be able to alter the database at runtime.

Comment: "The model may change at runtime (new tables, columns, ...)" this is not a good idea at all. Your database should define how you store the data and shouldn't change based on some conditions or parameters. The exception is raised by something related to your models. Please post the code for the models.

Comment: @Christian I have added the model class, it's quite simple. My thoughts are, if I can customize my model in its entirety using the fluent API, then there's nothing stopping me from changing the database in runtime and use a new instance of my DbContext with the nre model

Comment: Can you share `Test1ModelAEntity` class?

Comment: @Smit it's right there between the `GetOptions` method and the `Main` method

Comment: Probably this is due to incorrect model. ModelDiffer takes current model as baseline (which is also supposed to target model. In your case, you are initializing context using EmptyModel. Try using `test1Model`.

Comment: @Smit that does make some sense, but the `GetDifferences` method takes an `IModel source` and an `IModel target` parameters so it doesn't look into the model which the DbContext was initialized with. I did test it and got the same exception. I really believe it's got something to do with the conventions not being applied and the `Id` field not being extracted as key for the entity, which in turn causes the null exception when EF tries to get the key for the entity.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I debugged into the code. There are multiple point of failures causing to this. Essentially you don't have any conventions at all. IConventionSetBuilder is scoped service. You are not creating scope. It also has multiple registrations, you used just first one which is NullConventionSetBuilder. I suggest using direct method like `SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.Build` to create convention set because it does a lot of things to combine conventions from different providers and user code.

Comment: @Smit yes you are correct. I saw in their source that the intended use for the `IConventionSetBuilder` service is to provide a set of builders which sequentially override the previous builder's conventions (see `ConventionSet.CreateConventionSet` source) so using the Sql builder alone isn't enough as it's expecting core conventions to be applied first, which can be done using the `ICoreConventionSetBuilder` service. This makes the exception go away but I tried to do this without a DbContext and apparently I need it because conventions look into sets in the class  which I will investigate later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the comments which pointed me in the correct direction.

In summary, I was trying to create my models using an empty convention set. This obviously leads to all sorts of problems as you have to generate the entire model explicitly, which is very complex.

To use the expected convention set I had to get it from my context using `ConventionSet.CreateConventionSet`. I also had to manually validate my model before being able to use it in queries and insert commands. The rest of the logic is pretty much the same.

Here's my final code including the tests I ran to ensure everything worked as expected:

```
static DbContextOptions GetOptions(IModel model)
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
    builder
        .UseSqlServer(connStr)
        .UseModel(model);
    return builder.Options;
}

//Test 1
class Test1EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StrProp { get; set; }
}

//Test 2
class Test2EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StrProp { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Test2ModelBEntity> Children { get; set; }
}
class Test2EntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EntityAId { get; set; }
    public Test2EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var emptyModelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(new ConventionSet());
    var emptyModel = emptyModelBuilder.Model;
    using (var baseCtx = new TestContext(GetOptions(emptyModel)))
    {
        //Get all services we need from the base context
        var conventions = ConventionSet.CreateConventionSet(baseCtx);
        var migrationServices = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddDbContextDesignTimeServices(baseCtx)
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        //Test 1
        var test1ModelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(conventions);
        test1ModelBuilder.Entity<Test1EntityA>()
            .ToTable("EntityA");
        var test1Model = test1ModelBuilder.GetInfrastructure().Metadata;
        test1Model.Validate();

        var operations = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>().GetDifferences(emptyModel, test1Model);
        var commands = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator>().Generate(operations, test1Model);
        var connection = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IRelationalConnection>();
        migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationCommandExecutor>().ExecuteNonQuery(commands, connection);

        using (TestContext ctx = new TestContext(GetOptions(test1Model)))
        {
            ctx.Set<Test1EntityA>().Add(new Test1EntityA
            {
                StrProp = "test1",
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Test 2
        var test2ModelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(conventions);
        test2ModelBuilder.Entity<Test2EntityA>()
            .ToTable("EntityA");
        test2ModelBuilder.Entity<Test2EntityB>()
            .ToTable("EntityB");
        var test2Model = test2ModelBuilder.GetInfrastructure().Metadata;
        test2Model.Validate();

        operations = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationsModelDiffer>().GetDifferences(test1Model, test2Model);
        commands = migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator>().Generate(operations, test2Model);
        migrationServices.GetRequiredService<IMigrationCommandExecutor>().ExecuteNonQuery(commands, connection);

        using (TestContext ctx = new TestContext(GetOptions(test2Model)))
        {
            var e = new Test2EntityA
            {
                StrProp = "test2",
            };
            ctx.Set<Test2EntityA>().Add(e);
            ctx.Set<Test2EntityB>().Add(new Test2EntityB
            {
                EntityA = e,
            });
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine(ctx.Set<Test2EntityB>().Where(b => b.EntityA.StrProp == "test2").Count());
        }
    }
}
```